# Making an atmosphere that can handle multiple suns?

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I am trying to simulate a solar system with three suns. That works fine:
[Surface of planet looking at 2 suns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAmKi.jpg)

The problem is that it doesn't look great. I don't need a photorealistic image, but I want better than this. I have determined that the greatest problem is the lack of an atmosphere. I tried [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/open-source-atmospheric-scattering.419195/) but even after a couple hours messing with code and settings, it can only capture one sun at a time.

The next thing I tried was an inside-out sphere with a transparent material, with some success. The problem is that the suns reflect on the *opposite* side of the sphere, since it's inside out. This is the code I'm using to make it inside out, just in case it's important:

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;
public class FlipNormals : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Mesh mesh = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        Vector3[] normals = mesh.normals;
        for (int i = 0; i < normals.Length; i++)
            normals[i] = -1 * normals[i];
        mesh.normals = normals;
        for (int i = 0; i < mesh.subMeshCount; i++)
        {
            int[] tris = mesh.GetTriangles(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < tris.Length; j += 3)
            {
                //swap order of tri vertices
                int temp = tris[j];
                tris[j] = tris[j + 1];
                tris[j + 1] = temp;
            }
            mesh.SetTriangles(tris, i);
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking (with my rudimentary knowledge of lighting and polygons) that maybe having the sphere render on both sides might help, but I haven't found a way to do that nor do I have much hope for its success.

I was hoping someone else would have some better ideas?

Comment: You may find this video from Sebastian Lague interesting, where they implement an atmosphere via shaders (in Unity) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxfEbulyFcY